# Are all Eladrin CR 10?

Tags: dnd-5e, world-building, feywild, eladrin

With the release of *Mordenkainen's Tome of Foes* we get more information about the Eladrin and race options. The Eladrin listed are CR 10.

For someone who knows very little about Feywild lore, are Eladrin civilizations comprised of these CR 10 inhabitants or is this just examples of Eladrin for Mordenkainen?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## The Eladrin Monsters are not indicative of all Eladrin

They are just what you'd use if you wanted to set up a basic encounter against those types of Eladrin. Just like not every humanoid is equivalent to either a monster or a PC.

Comment: I would add that eladrin are a playable race as of mtf,